# flower (Celery monitoring tool) API - how does the tasks sorted?

Tags: celery, celery-task, celeryd, flower

I'm using flower API Reference to build my own monitoring tool.

When calling to: [GET /api/tasks](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#get--api-tasks) - how are tasks sorted? If I make a  request each minute, will I get the most newest tasks received? started? finished? Is there an option to choose sort method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flower relies on celery events. [Looks like](https://github.com/mher/flower/blob/10cef872a7d4a4022dfdb02ff705b434f94103a7/flower/utils/tasks.py#L15) all the tasks are sorted by their event timestamps.

Unfortunately, there is [no option to sort tasks](https://github.com/mher/flower/blob/10cef872a7d4a4022dfdb02ff705b434f94103a7/flower/api/tasks.py#L487-L489) as of now. However, it is very easy to modify the existing api to support sort.

Comment: Thanks for the refs. Just to clarify, I just understand the purpose of 'timestamp' field (because there are a lot of other time fields: received/success/started///) - it a dynamic field that updated with each event of the task

Comment: @chillar Anand how did you modify it without touching the extension since modification will lost when you reinstall it